# Code Igniter Login Validation Problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm building a test website for myself using Code Igniter and am struggling with Logins. I can create new users and store them in my database without any trouble according to phpMyAdmin, but am struggling with actually logging in.

My current code is:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->home();
}

public function home()
{
    $this->load->model('model_users');

    $data['emails'] = $this->model_users->getEmails();
    $data['users'] = $this->model_users->getUsers();

    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}

public function validate_credentials() {
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $query = $this->model_users->validate();


    if($query){
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('trade');
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('about_us');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
    <?php
class Model_users extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct(); //Call the model constructor
    }

    function validate() {
        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function create_member() {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');

        $new_user = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_user);
        return $insert;
    }

    function check_email_exists($email) {
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $result = $this->db->get('users');

        if($result->num_rows() > 0) {
            return FALSE; //email taken
        }else{
            return TRUE; //email available
        }
    }

    function getEmails() {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT email FROM users'); 

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        } else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    function getUsers() {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
   <body>    
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="login_form">

                        <?php if(isset($successful_creation)) { ?>
                            <h3><?php echo $successful_creation; ?></h3>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <h1><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Login</h1>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php
                        echo form_open('welcome/validate_credentials');
                        echo form_input('email', '', 'placeholder="Email"');
                        echo form_password('password', '', 'placeholder="Password" class="password"');
                        echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
                        echo anchor('signup', 'Create Account');
                        echo form_close();
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

When I hit Login on the Login page, I am always redirected to the About_Us page which I placed there just to test whether login was working or not. Are there any problems with my code that I'm overlooking? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show the result of print_r($result);

Comment: `var_dump()` your `$query` variable in your `validate()` function. If you keep getting redirected to the about us page, `validate()` is returning false. Check and double check the query.

Comment: @NavnitMishra okay I did that in check_email_exists, and it says this:

`( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 4 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )`

Comment: Inside the `validate()` function of your `Model_users` class. Something is happening where `num_rows` is not `==` to 1.

Comment: `num_rows()` [is a method](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#CI_DB_result::num_rows), not a property. You missed parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model update the `validate()` method, use `$query->num_rows()` instead of `$query->num_rows`.  It should be like this:

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Man thank you so much, it works perfectly now. Something so bloody small, I feel silly now. Thanks again!